# How to get current offset from UTC to Eastern Daylight Saving time using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am trying to get how many seconds Eastern Daylight Saving Time is different comparing to UTC right now (or anytime).

So for example right now UTC is 4h different (ahead) of Eastern Daylight Saving time = 4*3600 = 14400 seconds.
But in December that will change to 5h ahead.

How to write that programmatically so that script knows how many seconds is different any time it runs using momentjs?

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout [`moment-timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

const zone = 'US/Eastern';
const utc = 'UTC';

const diff = date => moment.tz(date, zone)
  .diff(moment.tz(date, utc), 'hours');

['2017-02-01', '2017-05-01', '2017-08-01', '2017-11-01'].forEach(date => {
  console.log(`${date}: ${diff(date)} hours`);
});
```

Output:

```
2017-02-01: 5 hours
2017-05-01: 4 hours
2017-08-01: 4 hours
2017-11-01: 4 hours
```